# Android: How to know what application is opened to foreground and do something when it goes to background

Tags: android, service, background, foreground

The title is bad, sorry. Could figure out how to say this in short.

So, I'm developing an application for Android which will only be used in my own couple tablets which are going to public use.

I need a service running in the background (or so I currently believe, prove me wrong if possible) which keeps track which application is foreground, and when that application goes to background the service starts activity which will go foreground and show something to the user(for example like some ad, or some review window which asks for start rating).

How could this be done?

Thank you.

E: The other applications can be 3rd party, so I can't modify the code of those.

Answer (score 0):

When u start other activity at that time you current activity is OnPause() state and other activity goes onCreate() State.

You Must refer [Activity LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Accessibility service. Starting from Android Lollipop you can't gather this kind of information. The only way is via accessibility [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html).

Comment: Better if you provide links instead official doc for achieving this

Answer (score 0):

to check other running tasks you should use ActivityManager.

```
   ActivityManager acm = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> Ru_tasks = acm.getRunningTasks(NUMBER_OF_TASKS_U_WANT);
    if (!Ru_tasks .isEmpty()) {
        LOOP FOR EACH TASK (i is counter)
        ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(i).topActivity; // Or replace .topactivity with task name
        if (topActivity.getPackageName().equals(WHAT_YOU LOOK FOR)) {
                  //Do WHAT YOU WANT!
        }
    }
```

get  GET_TASKS permission

Comment: I found this: "This method was deprecated in API level 21. As of LOLLIPOP, this method is no longer available to third party applications: the introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak person information to the caller. For backwards compatibility, it will still return a small subset of its data: at least the caller's own tasks, and possibly some other tasks such as home that are known to not be sensitive." So it's not anymore so nice option. I could keep the tablets at 4.4, but someday I probably want 5.0